# BIOS clock still slow after battery change

Tags: windows-7, performance, clock

Recently I discovered that my system clock was slowing down. I got a new CMOS battery and replaced the one already on the motherboard. Both of the batteries seemed to have good voltage with a tongue test. However, two days after I re-synchronized the clock over the internet, I have lost 9 minutes and 15 seconds.

Does anyone know what could be causing the problem? I read in another question that the Real Time Clock crystal might be at fault, does that seem to be the case here?

Custom built machine with a Gigabyte GA-770TA-UD3 motherboard and a AMD Phenom 955 BE @3.2GHz running Windows 7.

Comment: BIOS clocks are notoriously poor. That's even worse than average though...

Comment: http://vancouver-webpages.com/time/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use an HP/Apollo system for work which is **designed** so that the clock runs slowly, but a modern PC motherboard shouldn't do this.

You could use an NTP server to synchronise the clock to a time standard, but it should be able to keep better time (than you're seeing) without it.

I would agree with the theory which says it's the RTC crystal. What you're seeing may be an indication it's about to fail completely.

Answer (score 1):

If it really is not the battery, I would have to believe you have a motherboard problem. Check out this link for more on board time problems:

http://www.pcguide.com/ts/x/comp/mbsys/cmos_LosingTime.htm